# Accessing Fetched Resources From a Controller?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In my AngularJS controller I'm trying to do something relatively simple: I'm trying to populate a `<select>` element dynamically in the controller. To do so I need to wait for my localized UI text data to be loaded and data from my server to be loaded and this is causing a problem for me.

What my HTML Looks like:

```
<select 
data-ng-model="group"
data-ng-options="options.value as options.label for options in userGroups">
<option>--</option>
</select>
```

Then my controller is actually implementing a base controller "class" which allows me to share logic between controllers:

```
// exampleController.js
myModule.controller('exampleController',
    ['$scope', '$timeout', '$routeParams', '$controller',
        function ($scope, $timeout, $routeParams, $controller) {
            // Instantiate the base controller class and set it's scope 
            // to this controller's scope. This is how the base and child
            // controllers will share data and communicate.
            var base = $controller('baseController', { $scope: $scope });
}]);
```

And here is a relevant snippet of the baseController:

```
// baseController.js
$scope.getDataFromUrl = function (url, cache, successFunction) {
    $http.get(url, { cache: cache })
    .success(function (data) {
        if (!handleErrorInData(data))
        {
            successFunction(data);
        }
    });
};

$scope.getDataFromUrl(uiTextResourceUrl, true, function (data) {
    $scope.uiText = data;
});
```

So `baseController` fetches the text resources when it loads and sets it to the scope when it's finished retrieving the data. `exampleController` on the other hand will fetch other data from the server via the `getDataFromUrl()` function defined in `baseController` like so:

```
$scope.getDataFromUrl(dataUrl, false, function (data) {
    // Do stuff with the returned data...
};
```

My issue is coming from this part of the `exampleController` code where I populate the data of the `<select>` element from earlier:

```
// exampleController.js (Continued...)

$scope.getDataFromUrl(userGroupsUrl, false, function (data) {
    initSelectDropdown(data);
});

var initSelectDropdown = function (data) {
    var userGroups = [];

    // Parse data retrieved from the server and populate the <select> bound data
    // array with it
    var index;
    for (index = 0; index < data.length; ++index)
    {
        var newGroup = {
            value: data[index],
            label: data[index]
        };

        // One of the data entries will have a value of "", this group needs its
        // label to be set to the localized string "No Group"
        if (newGroup.value === "")
        {
            newGroup.label = '<' + $scope.uiText['NoGroup.Text'] + '>';
        }
        userGroups.push(newGroup);
    }

    // Set local userGroups to scope
    $scope.userGroups = userGroups;
};
```

The problem I'm having is here in the `initSelectDropdown()` function. I need to have both the data from the server and the uiText resource data from the server, particularly the line `newGroup.label = '<' + $scope.uiText['NoGroup.Text'] + '>';` where the data is being transformed in a way that is dependant on localized resources being loaded. I researched the issue and saw that using `$q.all()` might be a solution but unfortunately in my case there is no way for me to call `$q.all()` because the two calls to fetch data are being made from different functions in different controllers (data being requested from child controller and resources being requested from base controller).

In the view it's easy to fix this because if I bind an element to `$scope.uiText['SomeText.Text']` then it doesn't care if `SomeText.Text` is undefined at first and when it is eventually populated the UI will automatically pick up on the change.

How can I make this work? Is it possible to achieve something like how binding works in the view?

Answer (score 3):

For sharing code angular provides services/factory, you don't need to use base controller.

Define a factory class and add two methods, one to fetch your server data and other to fetch uiText data. these methods will return promises.

Now in your controller you can use $q.all() passing the two promises that will be resolved when ajax call is complete.
Hope it makes sense ?

Comment: We're using a base controller instead of a service because we didn't want to have to copy and paste the error handling function `handleErrorInData()` across every controller, along with other common fuctionality shared between all controllers. With your suggestion we would have to call the `$myService.fetchUiText()` in every controller along with defining the error handling function in every controller (which ultimately writes an error message to $scope, which is why that logic can't go in a service)

Comment: you have to define the handleError function inside a factory/service and inject that factory/service into the controllers that need it.

Comment: @apairet but it seems like bad practice to define handleError inside of a service because ultimately handleError will set $scope.error to some message if an error is encountered. And the "Angular Way" suggests that only controllers should ever modify the scope.

Comment: you have not shared the implementation of handleError, but is it not possible to write it in a way that on error it returns the error and then you can use it to set in scope from controller ? that ways scope will be modified only in controller and you can reuses method as well

Comment: `handleError()` is a big chunk of code which will do different things depending on the error including things like not just setting an error message such as redirecting the user to a different screen.